# Derangement and $1/e$ - how to make this proof rigorous?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

It is well known that the number of derangements (permutations $\sigma \in S_n$ with no fixed points) is given as
$$
D_n =  n!\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!}.
$$
From this, we can show that the probability of a given permutation to be a derangement converges to $1/e$ as $n$ goes to infinity. Now, here's a variation of the problem: for given $k$, what is the limit probability that the permutation of a sequence $(1, ..., 1, 2, ..., 2, ..., n, ..., n)$ (each $i \in [n]$ shows exactly $k$ times) is derangement as $n\to \infty$? I heard that one can find the number of such derangements in terms of Bernoulli polynomials and the answer is $1/e^k$, but I wonder if there's more easier way to show this.

In fact, here's my "proof": for $k=1$, for each position, the probability where $\sigma(i) \neq i$ will be $\frac{n-1}{n}$ as $n$ is large enough, so that the probablity will be the limit of $(\frac{n-1}{n})^{n}$, which is $1/e$. Similar arguments also works for general $k$. I think this "proof" is correct at least intuitively, but I wonder if this can be made rigorous.

Comment: Your "proof" would be called a *heuristic*, I think. It's invalidity is in the fact that the events $\sigma(i)\ne i$ are not independent for different $i$s. To make it rigorous presumably you could bound the dependence of these events and show how the difference between the heuristic and the true probability is affected by this bound.

Comment: to help calculate the probability where $\sigma(i)\neq i$ in your sequence to be $\frac{(nk-k)(nk-k-1)...(nk-2k)((nk-k)!)}{nk!}$

Comment: by derangement you mean $\sigma(i)\neq i$ or $\sigma(x)\neq i$ where $k\cdot (i-1)<x\leq k\cdot i$?

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the probability where $\sigma(i)\neq i$ in your sequence to be $\frac{(nk-k)(nk-k-1)...(nk-2k)((nk-k)!)}{nk!}$ then pair things up as $\frac{nk-k}{nk}\frac{nk-k-1}{nk-1}...\frac{nk-k-k}{nk-k}$ then by substitute $n+\frac{j}{k}$ for $n$ to get $\frac{nk-k}{nk}$ so the limit goes to $(\frac{nk-k}{nk})^k$, which when you raise to the $n$ power to include all $i$ gives the desired result is reached.